# Identify the page user is on in a .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

How can I identify the page the user is on in a .NET MAUI shell app?

To give a little more context, here's what I'm trying to do:

My .NET MAUI app -- using Shell -- has quite a few pages, some of which are defined as tab pages in `AppShell.xaml`. One of the pages provides a real-time chat feature using `SignalR`.

I'm trying to make the experience as similar as possible to the built-in chat feature in iOS and Android where:

- If the user is on the chat page -- in other words, actively participating in a chat -- a more subtle audio notification is played for any incoming message
- If the user is NOT on the chat page but actively using the app, a more audible notification is played to alert the user of the incoming message
- If the user is not using the device, then a system notification is used to alert the user

I'm using Azure Notification Hubs service to handle the third/last scenario but for me to handle the first two scenarios, I need to know what page the user is on so that I can determine what audio notification to use.

I have a `ChatService` that contains all the `SignalR` code to handle sending/receiving messages. In the `MessageReceived()` method, I need to determine user's page. So, this code won't be running in page code behind or a view model but in a service class which is why I need a more universal way of determining user's current "location" in my app.

Comment: Add an event handler on the service and have each interested page gain access to the service (via dependency injection) and subscribe to the event handler.

Comment: Thank you! This approach would work, though I was hoping for a built-in mechanism e.g. `Application.Current.ActivePage` or someting like that which would've been nice :-)

Comment: Maybe another idea is to examine the navigation stack? Not sure if this would be 100% reliable but it really should be.

Comment: AppShell.Current.CurrentPage

Comment: I thought it would be that straight forward. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using shell you can get the current page like :

```
var page = Shell.Current.CurrentPage;
```

If not you get it using:

```
var page = Application.Current.MainPage;
```